# React Horizontal Timeline distance of undefined error

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native, timeline

I'm trying to use [React Horizontal Timeline](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-horizontal-timeline) in my react app but I'm getting that error (pointing to line # 379 of react-horizontal-timeline.js):

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'distance' of undefined
```

My code includes:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import HorizontalTimeline from 'react-horizontal-timeline';

class Foo extends Component {
    state = {
        value : '01-01-1990',
        previous: 0
    };
    render(){
        const VALUES = ['20-04-1991'];
        return(){
            <div>
                <HorizontalTimeline values={VALUES} 
                    indexClick={(index) => {
                        this.setState({value: index, previous: this.state.value});
                    }} 
                />
                <div> {this.state.value} </div>
            </div>
        }
    }
}
export default Foo;
```

Can somebody please identify the real issue or alternatively suggest some good option for horizontal timeline for react?

Comment: Can this be used only with dates? is it possible to use it with strings instead of dates. I am just trying to use this package, getting all issues which you have faced, so wanted to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two main issues in the snippet posted in the question.

- Wrong Date Format: As per [the simple and limited documentation](https://github.com/sherubthakur/react-horizontal-timeline/), required format is `mm/dd/yyyy`. [Pointed out by @Mayank](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43451573/3151337)
- `index` declaration: It needs to define index first before using as `index={this.state.value}`

[See similar github issue](https://github.com/sherubthakur/react-horizontal-timeline/issues/22)

Answer (score 2):

**Changes**:

**1.** You are returning 2 elements from `render` method, you need to wrap them in a `div`.

Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43423023/5185595) for more explanation.

**2.** As per [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-horizontal-timeline) you attached, values needs an `array` of dates with `'mm/dd/yyyy'` format, but you are passing `'dd/mm/yyyy'`:

```
const VALUES = ['20-04-1991'];
```

Convert this to proper format:

```
const VALUES = ['04/20/1991'];
```

**Try this**:

```
render(){
        const VALUES = ['04/20/1991'];
        return(){
           <div>
               <HorizontalTimeline 
                  values={VALUES} 
                  indexClick={(index) => {
                      this.setState({value: index, previous: this.state.value});
                  }} 
               />
               <div className='text-center'>
                  {this.state.value}
               </div>
            </div>
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm actually returning it inside a body div in my real code that I forgot adding in the snippet here, edited now. I also converted date format but nothing worked, still getting the same error.

Comment: but you removed the values from ques, are you using that in your code ??

Comment: Sorry didn't get, which values are you talking about?

Comment: Yeah the error discussed in the question has been resolved by these changes. But I'm unable to successfully make the timeline as discussed in [that github issue](https://github.com/sherubthakur/react-horizontal-timeline/issues/22#issuecomment-304647557).